# Is it bad practice to install an IC to the other side of a heatsink?

Tags: integrated-circuit, heatsink

Normally, we connect an IC to the other side of a heatsink than shown here:

[image]

Is it bad to place the IC on the 'unusual' side of the heatsink (and if so, why?) or are both sides each equally functional? In the end I will place the heatsink upside down in the case, so with the ICs on top of the heatsink.

Comment: Better crop and scale down your image a bit before Olin sees it ;o)

Comment: Also you probably need to show how it fits in the final enclosure, otherwise that arrangement could go from far better to far worse so there's no generic answer.

Comment: Agree with @PeterJ. The performance for a heat sink can highly depend on its orientation (due to air flow).

Comment: Thanks, I changed it - please ask more information if you need it :-)

Comment: "Is the style in the image bad?" - YES, but mainly because of the horrific soldering and mass of uninsulated contacts. Whatever you are doing, you're not doing it very well (and I mean "well" in terms of care, neatness, quality, reliability, safety...)

Comment: Yes, this was very hasty work. (The image is a bit blurry because of motion, that doesn't help either.) I'm of course asking about the heatsink-style. What about that?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the unusual side - I see this quite often?

Comment: If the surface quality and coating is the same on both sides, it probably doesn't make a significant difference from the perspective of heat conduction away from the IC.

Comment: If those IC's are standing vertically and the heatsink is not supported in any way other than the solder joints of the IC, then the "usual" way of doing it puts the center of mass closer to being balanced over the pins, not exerting a torque on them. :)

Comment: On the other hand, the "unusual" way is more open in the sense that the heat is being pulled farther away from the IC. The IC isn't cradled in the heat sink.  The heat sink is in actual fact pulling heat farther away from the IC.  The aggregate is more of an unfolded structure in this configuration.

Comment: @Kaz can you make that an answer? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of a heatsink is to move heat away from some component that would otherwise get too hot and dissipate that heat into the air.  This means the surfaces of the heatsink needs to be open to free air.  Putting anything other than the part that produces the heat onto a heatsink will decrease its effectiveness.  Putting something that produces its own heat there makes it even worse.  Then there is also the additional issue of whether the extra part can handle the temperature.  So, the short answer it that this is not a good idea.

However, this does not meant it is guaranteed to fail.  If everything isn't running at its thermal limit, then the heatsink has extra capacity, and some degradation of that capacity can be tolerated.  Still, this is not something I'd do except as a last resort, and then with some careful analisys to make sure everything is OK.

Comment: It's not clear that the question proposes to put parts on both faces of the heatsink, I'm reading it more about asking if one face is better than the other.  My gut instinct would be that the side away from the fins could actually be a tiny bit better, since the package itself wouldn't be in the pocket of hot air between them - on the other hand, if there cooling air aimed at the fin side, then that side might be better.

Comment: That's more what I meant, yes. Sorry for any misunderstanding and Olin: thanks for your explanation which was sure very useful! @ChrisStratton, can you make this an answer?

Comment: In particular, in this picture the electrolytic caps are going to be at almost the same temperature as the ICs.  It's not kind to electrolytics to cook them like this.

Comment: @markrages good point. I'll change it asap.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is natural cooling convection , the position of heat source (the device), as well as the orientation of heatsink-device system plays important role, some times in a magnitude of 10 oC.
So if your thermal design it is critical and close to Tj max, then you have to put the devices in the recomended place in order to achive maximum cooling performance.
For temperatures up to 150 oC the life expectancy of semiconductor halves for every 10~15 oC and up to 175 oC halves for every 5~10 oC